# Observable Binding With Knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

When I run this html page and click on some option from select element the value of price automatically changes. How it is possible ? Can you explain the function and what role value of select `elementvalue: meal,` play here ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Working with Lists and Collections</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.1.0.debug.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
            var self = this;
            self.name = name;
            self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
        }

        // Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
        function ReservationsViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
            self.availableMeals = [
                { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
                { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
                { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
            ];

            // Editable data
            self.seats = ko.observableArray([
                new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
                new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
            ]);

            // Operations
            self.addSeat = function () {
                self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Your seat reservations</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Passenger name</th>
                    <th>Meal</th>
                    <th>Surcharge</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how knockout is designed to work. I'd suggest going through the [Knockout Tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) to understand it better.

But in answer to your question, your `select` is set to display: `$root.availableMeals`, which is an Array of all meals, defined:

```
self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];
```

Each item in the array has 2 properties: `mealName`, which is the display value in the `select` and `price`, which is used in the `Surcharge` column. The display value is set with: `optionsText: 'mealName'`.

Your UI allows you to select an option from this list, and the selection is saved using: `value: meal`, which is defined as an observable per seat reservation, defined with a default value:

```
self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
```

Once a selection is made and this value has been updated, knockout gets to work on the value to display on the `Surcharge` column.

Because the meal choice has been updated and it's `observable`, the price automatically changes to be in line with the meal selection, as your binding is configured to return the `price` of the selected meal for the seat reservation.

```
<td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
```

### [JSFiddle For Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/ag4Mn/)